# Saving best results from a main matrix into another matrix

Tags: matlab

trying to save 10 best results (smaller results are better) from particle.Best into another matrix called BestPositionMatrix in matlab .
Is there any better or shorter way to write the same code?

```
 [~, n]=sort([particle.Cost]);

        BCostIndexes= n(1:10);

        BestPositonsMatrix=[[particle(BCostIndexes(1)).Position];[particle(BCostIndexes(2)).Position]...
            ;[particle(BCostIndexes(3)).Position];[particle(BCostIndexes(4)).Position];[particle(BCostIndexes(5)).Position];
        [particle(BCostIndexes(6)).Position];[particle(BCostIndexes(7)).Position];[particle(BCostIndexes(8)).Position]...
         ;[particle(BCostIndexes(9)).Position];[particle(BCostIndexes(10)).Position];[particle(BCostIndexes(11)).Position]];
```

The  BestPositionMatrix for 5 best result is 
BestPositonsMatrix =

```
    0.0421   -0.0521   -0.2718   -0.1106    0.1674
    0.0596   -0.0745    0.1338   -0.2550    0.1008
    0.0561   -0.0384   -0.1041   -0.0820    0.1458
    0.0260   -0.0697   -0.0509   -0.0968   -0.0004
    0.0231   -0.0708   -0.0785   -0.1268   -0.0119
```

the position for each particle is a vector

Comment: What are the dimensions of the Position vector? 5x1 or 1x5? Can you clarify the input dimensions and how you want to store this in the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when `Position` is a n-by-1 vector, you can use:

```
[~,I] = sort([particle.Cost]);
BestPositonsMatrix = [particle(I(1:m)).Position].';   % transpose to make vector
```

with `m` the number of best results you want to keep.

When `Position` is a 1-by-n vector, you will have to do a reshape to get a m-by-n matrix:

```
BestPositonsMatrix = reshape([particle(I(1:m)).Position], n, m).';
```

Comment: the position for each particle is a vector